# SIR model error - can't find bug, need help in locating potential source of deviation?

Tags: netlogo

This question will be an interesting one. I was trying to replicate the results of a [paper](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Elatora/buscarino_jump_38002_epl08.pdf) which concerned disease transmission in a system of freely moving agents (sounds like the perfect job for NetLogo). I coded up a simple SIR model in NetLogo pretty easily according to the details given in the paper, made sure my model parameters matched those listed, and let the simulation run. Everything ran perfectly until I checked how the experimental results matched with the predicted values (according to the results of the paper). They were off, and by a pretty sizeable margin. Thinking there was an error somewhere in the code, I triple checked everything, only to find *nothing*. I then made sure the ordering of events was correct (as the order of movement, infection, and recovery matters), and these also matched the paper. I mulled over the problem for quite some time until finally I opened R, coded up the exact same program in RStudio, and let it run, only to find that the results matched the prediction perfectly! The R code does the same thing I *expect* the NetLogo code to be doing, so I think that something is going on behind the scenes in NetLogo or I've a misunderstanding somewhere that is the source of the deviation... Note that since the result in the paper is a mean-field approximation, you would have to run the program a few times in order for it to approach the theoretical result.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, as my R code confirms the predicted values are correct, so I conclude that something *somewhere* in my NetLogo code is incorrect. I'm not too familiar with NetLogo, and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me find where in the following code the deviation may be occurring. The experimental average tends to be lower than the predicted one, suggesting that infection occurs faster than it should, but of all the changes I looked at, none of them solved this problem (e.g. infections do not occur one at a time per infectious turtle). Any suggestions/help would be very much appreciated.

A slimmed-down version of my code is presented below. This should run in a regular interface with the standard setup/go buttons. Results are stored in lists that can be plotted, and anyone curious can see the deviation as the simulation progresses via the Plot object. Thank you in advance.

```
;; Simple SIR model
globals [
  ;; variables for storing predictions
  predS
  predE
  predI
  predR
  oldPredS
  oldPredE
  oldPredI
  oldPredR

  ;; list to store experimental values
  Slist
  ;; list to store predicted values
  predSList 
  
  ;; model variables
  length-of-patch ;; length of habitat (a square of area length-of-patch^2)
  infection-radius ;; the distance from an infectious individual a susceptible agent has to be within
  ;; in order to risk getting infected
  total-pop ;; total population in the model
  force-of-infection ;; probability of infection if within infection-radius distance
  I0 ;; initial infected
  recovery-rate ;; probability of recovery
]

turtles-own [
  infected-status ;; 0 susceptible, 1 infected, 2 recovered
]

to setup
  ca ;; clear
  
  ;; define the variables
  set length-of-patch 31.62278 ;; the square root of 1000 (so the density is 1)
  set infection-radius 1
  set total-pop 1000
  set force-of-infection 0.1
  set I0 10
  set recovery-rate 0.05
  
  ;; setup simulation
  setup-patches
  setup-agents
  reset-ticks
  
  ;; initialize lists as empty
  set Slist []
  set predSList []
end


to go
  ;; update experimental values (density of susceptible individuals)
  set Slist lput ((count turtles with [infected-status = 0]) / (length-of-patch ^ 2)) Slist
  
  if (ticks = 0) ;; if ticks == 0, make sure initial value is the same as experimental
  [
    ;; update predicted values with densities of agents
    set predS ((count turtles with [infected-status = 0]) / (length-of-patch ^ 2)) 
    set predI ((count turtles with [infected-status = 1]) / (length-of-patch ^ 2))  
    set predR 0
    ;; placeholder variables for iterative process
    set oldPredS predS
    set oldPredI predI
    set oldPredR predR

    ;; store predicted S population in corresponding list
    set predSList lput (predS) predSList
  ]
  if (ticks > 0) ;; if ticks > 0, then update predicted values according to paper results
  [
    ;; update predicted values
    set predI (oldPredI + oldPredS * (1 -  (1 - force-of-infection * oldPredI) ^ (pi * (infection-radius ^ 2))) - recovery-rate * oldPredI)
    set predR (oldPredR + recovery-rate * oldPredI)
    set predS ((total-pop / (length-of-patch ^ 2)) - predI - predR)
    ;; placeholder variables
    set oldPredS predS
    set oldPredI predI
    set oldPredR predR

    ;; store values in corresponding list
    set predSList lput (oldPredS) predSList
  ]


  ;; perform movement, infection, and recovery, in that order
  move-agents
  infect-agents
  recover-agents

  if (count turtles with [infected-status = 1] = 0) [
    ;; if no one else is infected, stop
    stop
  ]
 
  tick
end


to setup-patches
  ;; resize the world to make it fit comfortably in the interface
  resize-world 0 length-of-patch 0 length-of-patch 
  set-patch-size 400 / (length-of-patch)
end

to setup-agents
  ;; create susceptible agents
  crt (total-pop - I0) [
    set infected-status 0
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set color 55 ;; green
    set size 2
  ]
  ;; create I0 infected agents
  crt I0 [
    set infected-status 1
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set color 15 ;; red
    set size 2
  ]
end


to move-agents ;; move all the agents
  ask turtles [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
end

to infect-agents
  ;; iterate over infected turtles
  ask turtles with [infected-status = 1] [
    ;; check neighborhood around infected turtle for susceptible turtles...
    let numNeighbors count (turtles with [infected-status = 0] in-radius infection-radius)
    
    if (numNeighbors > 0) [ ;; there are susceptibles around, so we perform infection
      ask (turtles with [infected-status = 0] in-radius infection-radius) [
        let %draw (random-float 1)
        if (%draw <= force-of-infection) [ ;; probability of infection
          ;; infect one of the neighbors
          set infected-status 1
          set color 15 ;; red
        ]
      ] 
    ] ;; end of if numneighbors > 0
  ]
end

to recover-agents
  ask turtles with [infected-status = 1] [
    let %draw (random-float 1)
    if (%draw <= recovery-rate) [ ;; an agent recovered
      set infected-status 2
      set color 105
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: (1) when you coded in R and got the predictions correct, is that with agents or with differential equations? (2) where does your infection-radius come from?

Comment: Which version of NetLogo are you using?

Comment: @JenB (1) it is with agents (points in a plane), (2) my infection-radius is arbitrarily chosen, but was set to 1 in the paper, so I did the same (let me know if this answers your question)

Comment: @Jasper I am using version 6.1.0

Comment: There were some bugs with the `in-radius` primitive in NetLogo 6.1.0, can you switch to NetLogo 6.1.1 and try your model again?

Comment: @Jasper I downloaded 6.1.1 and the problem remains - the experimental values still lie below the predicted values by a large margin

Comment: I took a quick look at the model code and one thing jumped out - you're using a fractional size (31.62278) for the world `max-pxcor` and `max-pycor`.  NetLogo will let you do this, but it will round the value down, so your world size is actually 31.  Also, NetLogo expects there to be "middle row/column", so the actual values for turtle `xcor`/`ycor` positions will be from `-0.5` to `31.499...`, which is probably different than your R-coded model.  Any chance these world sizing differences are the cause(s) of the discrepancies?

Comment: @Jasper good point Jasper, see my comment under JenB's answer. There's still something else going awry since the results are still not in agreement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I can see is that you have: `setxy random-pxcor random-pycor` but you want: `setxy random-xcor random-ycor`

Basically you are putting all your turtles at the centre of the patch, so they are on top of each other, instead of distributing them randomly across the space. That positioning changes the distribution of possible distances between turtles.

I also changed the number of turtles to <strike>1024</strike> 1089 and the size to sqrt 1024 (instead of 1000) to make the density match properly.

Both of those reduced the mismatch but it's unclear whether they fix the problem since I didn't do large numbers of runs.

UPDATE

Even more dimension matching is required. Changing the code so there are 1089 agents, setting length to 33 for the pred calculations, and resizing world with max of 32 appears to move the curves closer. This recognises that patch coordinates 0 to 32 actually describe a size with length 33 because NetLogo coordinates would start at -0.5 and run to 32.5 as mentioned by @Jasper

Comment: Good catches! I implemented both changes and the deviation narrowed, but there is still deviation between the mean-field result and the theoretical prediction. I know that the results can be tighter, as the results of the R simulation were indistinguishable after only 200 sims (I cranked it up to 500 for the above simulation, but there is still room for improvement)

Comment: Also, I noticed that the landscape is not by default a torus, so I made these changes as well. There is still a gap, but I'm curious as to whether the in-radius function will carry over the same intuition on a torus? That is, an agent at (0,16) is in-radius 1 of a turtle at (32,16)?

Comment: yes, in-radius recognises the edge wrapping. you can check this by opening an `inspect` window for a turtle near the edge and type `ask turtles in-radius 2 [set color blue]` (or similar)

Comment: how did you do the equivalent of `in-radius` in R? R doesn't have the spatial awareness.

Comment: the equivalent of in-radius was obtained with a handy metric, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123947/calculate-distance-between-two-x-y-coordinates

Comment: Just curious but why are there 1089 patches? One would think after setting the length of the habitat to 32, the total number of patches would be 1024

Comment: Because you don't set length to 32, you set maximum (patch) coordinate to 32, but minimum is 0. Therefore there are 33 patches (0, 1, 2...32) with edge length of 1. The co-ordinate system will go from -0.5 to 32.5, a length of 33 (as mentioned by @Jasper).

Comment: That makes sense - thank you for the clarification. There seems to be only a small amount of deviation from the mean-field approximation, so I am accepting this answer. Thank you so much, everyone!

Comment: one more question, based on your most recent comment. When I edit the habitat, it says the coordinates on either axis are [0,32], but you're saying that the coordinate system instead is of length 33 and is of the range [-0.5, 32.5]? This is very strange... adjusting these numbers makes the mean-field approx. agree much better, but I'm curious as to why the very confusing convention of reporting incorrect coordinate axes...

Comment: There is nothing incorrect or inconsistent about the axes. The patch is a unit square centred on integer values of the coordinate system. So the patch centred at 0,0 on the coordinate system extends from -0.5,-0.5 (SW corner) to -0.5,0.5 (NW) to 0.5,0.5 (NE) to 0.5,-0.5 (SE). It would have the patch coordinates of 0 0. And a turtle for example at 0.2, 0.2 would be on this patch. This gets back to your original error where you were using `pxcor` (patch x coordinate) instead of `xcor` (turtle x coordinate).